# Cause: aapt2 is missing on 'C:\Users\Awaisi3\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt2.exe'

Tags: aapt2

[trying to develop a simple app for Android device. After updating this error appearing when I test my app, don't know much about these sort of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bgyd1.jpg)

Cause: aapt2 is missing on 'C:\Users\Awaisi3\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt2.exe'

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To improve your chances of getting an answer, ask a good question. Please check [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Sorry for the fast text question will try my best next time thank you for your kind comment

Answer (score 1):

Well, it looks like the file `C:\Users\Awaisi3\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\27.0.3\aapt2.exe` is either missing or is corrupt. Try re-installing build tools 27.0.3 through the SDK manager.

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply How can re-install build tools please guide

Comment: Use the SDK manager. You can get it from https://developer.android.com/studio/#downloads ('Command line tools only' for your platform, Windows)

Comment: Or if you're using android studio you can just use the sdk manger in android studio.